# Azure work account blocked when created home account with same email address

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services

The initial situation was where I had an Azure Portal account and I still have this account (name: tojas-work, email: tojas@something.com). This account appears as a Work/School account on Azure. This account is also the admin account for an Active Directory organization. That organization has more users in Active Directory.

I tried to create services in the tenant where I have the admin account (name: tojas-work). For this to do, I had to add subscriptions to the tenant. I couldn't do it, because I received an error message from Azure, that the account I have, cannot add subscriptions and the way I have to do it, is to create an account with the email address (tojas@something.com) that I have for the account.

I did it, I registered another account with the same email address (name: tojas-personal, email: tojas@something.com). I didn't know what will happen, but finally it created a personal account for me.

With that personal account (tojas-personal), now I can add subscriptions, but I cannot login to my work account (tojas-work) anymore. It says that my password is not correct and when I try to reset the password, it says that the account doesn't exist.

What can I do in this case to access my work account?

Comment: I had a work account and I was the administrator. Now I think I have it, because I didn't delete it, but I cannot access the account at all. My colleagues can see it as active in the Active Directory listing, but they cannot do anything with it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for confusion. The work account that I cannot access now, has administrator privileges.

Comment: I see what's wrong with the description. Thank you for correcting it. So, yes, it still  have active directory users.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to clarify the situation based on your questions. Do you think the issue is more clear now?

Comment: Yes I think that's a lot more clear. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer for you, but hopefully someone else will know.